# Setting timezone to London on android studio from Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am returning my documents from firestore in a recyclerView. These documents are returning a different time from the time they are set to on Firestore. I wish to make these times for London. Here is my code retrieving the timestamp from Firestore.

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SessionHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Session model) {

    holder.textViewModule.setText(model.getModule());
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.textViewDate.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.textViewStart.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.textViewStart.setText(String.valueOf(model.getStartTime()));
    holder.textViewEnd.setText(String.valueOf(model.getEndTime()));
    //holder.textViewID.setText(model.getDocumentID());


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set London timeZone like this and then format date and time using it.

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
java.sql.Time timeValue = new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(String.valueOf(model.getStartTime())).getTime())
```

This is the list of all [timeZones](https://gist.github.com/arpit/1035596) available.

Comment: plus where do I add this to my code. It will not accept this anywhere

Comment: add this where you want to change the timezone

Comment: I am retrieving these values from Cloud Firestore and they can only be retrieved using String.valueOf so where abouts do I put this code

Comment: then you need to convert your string to dateTime format

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: Firebase is returning a string(that is formatted as a date time). Anubhav's answer is just having you pass that string into the code he wrote above(startDate variable). It's then setting the timezone to London. His code can go anywhere you choose. You can implement it in your Model's getStartTime() and getEndTime(), so it'll always return the correct timezone if you want. You just need to make sure the SimpleDateFormat he gives, matches what Firebase's format is.

Comment: so could I just place this code into the get method in my session model class?

Comment: What do you want after changing the time zone meaning where this changed data goes?